# Split a PDF page in two parts

Tags: java, pdf, split, itext

I would like to take a single-page PDF, and than split it in two parts (cutting that page in the middle), without considering the text on that page. I'm using iText, but I don't find any examples on how to do this.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to tile a page? Tiling pages is explained in [Chapter 6](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-6-reusing-existing-pdf-documents) of the [iText 7 Jumpstart tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/). In that example, a page is split in four parts, but it's fairly easy to adapt the code so that it is split in two.

Comment: seems good what you linked, but I don't understand the code and the functions. I don't understand where he starts to copy a part of pdf and "paste" a new one

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really split a page, it would be a quite difficult task, what you can do is to clone content of a page inside a new one with half its original size, and repeat for the second page applying a translation to the content.

I show an example with [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) , I'm using it lately and I had a sandbox project ready to do the test, surely you can do the same with iText.

```
package printit;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;

public class CutIt {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PDDocument outdoc = new PDDocument();
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("sample_1.pdf"));
        PDPage page = (PDPage) doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);

        PDRectangle cropBox = page.getCropBox();
        float upperRightY = cropBox.getUpperRightY();
        float lowerLeftY = cropBox.getLowerLeftY();

        cropBox.setLowerLeftY(upperRightY/2);
        page.setCropBox(cropBox);
        outdoc.importPage(page);


        cropBox = page.getCropBox();
        cropBox.setUpperRightY(upperRightY/2);
        cropBox.setLowerLeftY(lowerLeftY);
        page.setCropBox(cropBox);
        outdoc.importPage(page);

        outdoc.save("cut.pdf");
        outdoc.close();


        doc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would do that, clone the content in a new pdf file. I found:     float width= pdf.getPage(n).getPageSize().getWidth();
            float height= pdf.getPage(n).getPageSize().getHeight(); than I can create a template of a new page but I don't know how select the content of one

Comment: The question was about iText, not about PDFBox. A link to an iText answer was added.